# Cannot Work PHP?

Tags: windows, php, web, iis

I have recently started to upgrade my intranet server to PHP but i am having trouble getting the code to work.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" x-undefined>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- php data test -->
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Sat, 31 Oct 2014 00:00:00 GMT">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
  </body>
</html>

<?php
   // Connect to MSSQL and select the database
   mssql_connect('intranet', 'sa', 'bobby123');
   mssql_select_db('phptable');

   // Send a select query to MSSQL
   $query = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM [php].[dbo].[persons]');

   // Construct table
   echo '<h3>Table structure for \'persons\'</h3>';
   echo '<table border="1">';

   // Table header
   echo '<thead>';
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>UserID</td>';
   echo '<td>Username</td>';
   echo '<td>Password</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
   echo '</thead>';

   // Dump all fields
   echo '<tbody>';

   for ($i = 0; $i < mssql_num_fields($query); ++$i) {
      // Fetch the field information
      $field = mssql_fetch_field($query, $i);

      // Print the row
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>' . $field->userid . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $field->username . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $field->password . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
   }

   echo '</tbody>';
   echo '</table>';

   // Free the query result
   mssql_free_result($query);
?>
```

I am using PHP 5.4 and have also tried to use 5.5 Is this something in my code, or do i need to install a plugin or something onto my server? (Windows Server 2012 R2)

Comment: I reccomend you to start with a simpler test just like `<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>` and if it works then go to more complicated tests.

Comment: the simple hello world displays the page perfectally?

Comment: perfectly (it wont let me edit it...)

Comment: Did you even read the PHP documentation on the MSSQL interface? This is wrong in almost every way it could be. I’ll point you at a single function: [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php). After setting that, RTFM (there are complete examples!) and use [so].

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any extra plugin.
Don't remove exceptions from your code.
If it is there u can simply find position of error.

Change statements like

> mssql_connect('intranet', 'sa', 'bobby123');

to

> mssql_connect('intranet', 'sa', 'bobby123') or die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');

Is intranet a domian name?

Comment: I am connecting to the intranet using "http://intranet:999/index.php" (my test server). The 'or die' did not work either. .

Answer (score 0):

It might be some Database connectivity problem.

Obtain the exact Host name, Database name, User name & Password and name of the particular Table Name.

Make your code like as below

```
$connect = mssql_connect('hostname','username','password');
$db = mssql_select_db('database');
```

Also please add  `mysql_error ()` function to identify the error.

Give the exact table name in the SQL statement instead of `[php].[dbo].[persons]`

Comment: that made no change to anything. Except you need to add a ; at the end of mssql_error() because it is a function